# How to use Core Data & iCloud between iOS & OS X

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data, icloud, swift2

I’m trying to get the newest Core Data & iCloud stack to work between iOS & OS X devices, but there are errors from the framework which aren’t very clear to me, because they expose inner Core Data mechanisms that aren’t documented at all.

After some research, a couple of unanswered questions on Apple’s official developer forums and a ticket (http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6071363555033088) I’m asking you, one of the greatest programmer’s communities, for help. Did you stumble upon a similar issue?

Do you know what this pesky error really means and how I can code around it?

```
[PFUbiquityFilePresenter processPendingURLs]_block_invoke(447): CoreData: Ubiquity:  Librarian returned a serious error for starting downloads Error Domain=BRCloudDocsErrorDomain Code=5 "No document at URL"
```

It looks like iOS expects transaction (`.cdt`) files, but can’t find them (or doesn’t have access to them?) and hence won’t apply any changes. Logically this would make sense, but so did burning witches.

Comment: Try building and testing the apps from here (http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/) and if you encounter the same problem log a bug with Apple.

Comment: I tried the linked Core Data stack, but unfortunately it still doesn’t work. It even creates a bigger mess, because it seems to handle transaction files in a custom way which generates dozens of duplicates on one device. Data sync is only one way. The only changes I made were the Bundle ID and Core Data container string.

Comment: duplicates is no problem, that will be because of the seed data that gets created.  The main thing to check is whether you are getting the same error now.  If not then that's a start.  Not sure what you mean by 'transaction files' or 'custom way' - all the code is using standard OSX and iOS APIs.

Comment: I’ve seen a couple of log entries from your stack where it states that transaction files aren’t uploaded / downloaded. My assumption was that you are handling the transaction files all by yourself in order to get rid of some pesky iCloud Core Data errors. The error message disappeared, so that’s a start. Synchronisation only works from OS X → iOS (in contrast to the other project where it worked the other way around). Do you use your code in production? Do you have meaningful data about iCloud related bugs in relation to all other bugs?

Comment: I check the state of the log files in order to determine whether all files (that are visible to the device) have been uploaded, actual import is usually pretty quick once the files have been downloaded - I don't touch them in any way though.  You can turn off loading the seed data, just comment out the relevant code.  That code does not handle all the edge cases yet.

Comment: What version of OSX, iOS and XCode are you using?  Sync has been somewhat broken under the 10.11, iOS9, XCode 7 betas.  Looks like the latest XCode release fixes some of the problems but more testing required. Under 10.10 and iOS8.4 things were pretty reliable.

Comment: BTW I have just installed all the latest beta's and the syncing seems to be working reliably again - the syncing was not working but after I recompiled all the apps they started syncing again - including all the previous transactions that had not synced prior to the recompile.  At some point  I'll rebuild the sample app and test it again - and update the code with the latest production core data stack manager.

Comment: Duncan, thanks for your efforts. I just downloaded the latest Xcode Beta and I will try my luck with it. I’m referring to the current OS betas only. The results I posted a couple of hours ago were all under iOS 9.0 (13A4325c) & OS X 10.11 (15A279b). I tested in the simulator and on the device. The results were the same and somehow unreliable.